# Decompile with Reflector

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

I have done decompile the code. But instead of display string, it display an negative number. How can I find the original string?
My decompiled code like this:

```
string str = .(-812265445);
```

it should be:

```
string str = "My string";
```

Please help
Note, when I add reference to project and debug, it can see the string "My string" not .(-812265445);
When I use another disassembler program, it display:

```
string str = ACK. STX(-812265445);
```

I guest ACK and STX are binary characters.

### Many thanks

Response for your answers are two pictures I took from ILSpy for better imagine:

Comment: I doubt any disassembler will be able to net you back the exact original source code.

Comment: @harold Que? what is "can you should"?

Comment: @OskarKjellin a mistake, I meant "can you show"

Comment: L_0012: ldc.i4 -812265440  
    L_0017: call string ::(int32)  
    L_001c: stloc.0   
    L_001d: ldc.i4 -812265445  
    L_0022: call string ::(int32)  
    L_0027: stloc.s str5

Comment: @akari so apparently `::` is a function and it looks up a string from that int, are you using an obfuscator?

Comment: ACK.STX() may be a static method call to get the decrypted string.

Comment: I am not a lawyer.  But beware when decompiling code that you might be violating licensing terms.  If the code is obfuscated (like this seems to be), it is a strong possibility that they don't want you doing it...

Answer (score 3):

Chances are the string is encrypted ... or its a bug in Reflector.  If its encrypted this won't help (the debugger is your best bet because encryptors inject the decrypt code right before your application uses the string).

To find a string in a compiled assembly using Reflector and ILDasm:

1. Open Reflector and find the member/method you are investigating
2. Change the language from C# to IL (in order to see what ILDASM will show you)
3. Verify the string is still not showing correctly
4. Get the line label beside the instruction (example: L_0060: )
5. Open your assembly in ILDasm and find the method you are investigating
6. Locate the instrucion label from Relector (should be the same line like IL_0060: )
7. If the string is still not correct here, then the string has been encrypted

To verify what string is stored in the assembly, you can do the following:

1. In ILDasm, close the dialog showing the IL for the method
2. Go to the View menu and Check Show Tokens
3. Open the method up again in ILDASM, this time when you locate your line of code it should have a token after it like /*  70002C92 */ (of course your number will be different) but this is where the string is located in the user strings metadata heap of the assembly.
4. Go to the View -> Meta Info and check Raw:Heaps
5. Go to the View -> Meta Info and Show!
6. In this new dialog, go to the Find Menu and put your token in there and click find

That should take you to the entry in the User Strings metadata heap and show you exactly what string was compiled in the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [Telerik Decompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Decompiling won't return the original code.

Your example looks like a simple 'load register with address of string, do something with it...'.

The compiler doesn't put strings (or any data) inline with the instructions, the data, strings, numbers, are all moved to appropriate sections.  Since this is a string constant, it's likely moved into the .data or .rodata section.

Converting your -812265445 number to hex makes it a little clearer, since it becomes 0xCF95D01B, a valid address to store something.  If your output-radix is signed decimal (the usual it seems), then addresses often end up huge negative values.  Convert them to hex or change your defaults to let you see (or more easily grok) where they point.

```
L_0012: ldc.i4 -812265440  (0xCF95D020)
L_0017: call string ::(int32)
L_001c: stloc.0
L_001d: ldc.i4 -812265445  (0xCF95D01B)
L_0022: call string ::(int32)
L_0027: stloc.s str5
```

From this (your comment above), it's plain there is a 'load register with address of the string' on line 0x12 (L_0012), a call to 'string::...' to convert it (I suppose) and then a store to put the resultant 'string' pointer somewhere.

Then you do it again on lines 0x1D-0x27.  Maybe with a 4 byte long const char string there (since the first and second load (ldc.i4) addresses are 5 units apart. (4 chars + 0 terminator).

Use your debugger or whatever you have to display the memory at those addresses shown (use whatever's actually in your current program disassembly though) and see what's there.  Explore!

Comment: I doubt they're addresses, it's possible I guess but then this code would break on 64bit, and besides they're much too high. It's also not something the regular C# compiler would do, it always uses `ldstr`. The call is also not exactly `string::`, the `string` part is just the return type there. So in all, I would say they're obfuscated indexes into a possibly encrypted string pool, something an obfuscator would do.

Comment: You're kidding, right?    The 'string::(int32)' is just a placeholder for a linked function call, it doesn't describe its return value or even required values, although I can surmise that it does something with the value of a 'variable' (i4), and returns a value which is stored.  Had to look up 'IL'... it's Microsoft's byte-code .NET stuff.  Nasty.  But it's certainly a load/call/store sequence, and being MS's .NET, it's processed before being executed, so the program is likely data to the IL interpreter, which could possibly shove it high in ram.  Especially on a big RAM 64-bit machine.

Comment: Are *you* kidding? Do you even know how MSIL works? The C# compiler and any other sane compiler will always use `ldstr` to load a string, because that's what `ldstr` is for. The only reason to avoid it is obfuscation. And addresses would have to be in a `nativeint`, not an `int32`. And yes, it does describe its return value and also its argument, because that's how MSIL works.

Comment: Nope, I don't know the details, don't care to at this time. I doubt they're any different than any other compiler, and I'll gracefully concede to your greater wisdom.  My apologies for offending you with my obtuseness. :) Thank you for teaching me.

Comment: No problem, I guess MSIL is just less low-level than you expected